# Output UNIX environment as JSON

Tags: json, environment-variables, jq

I'd like a unix one-liner that will output the current execution environment as a JSON structure like: { "env-var" : "env-value", ... etc ... }

This kinda works:

```
(echo "{"; printenv | sed 's/\"/\\\"/g' | sed -n 's|\(.*\)=\(.*\)|"\1"="\2"|p' | grep -v '^$' | paste -s -d"," -; echo "}")
```

but has some extra lines and I think won't work if the environment values or variables have '=' or newlines in them.

Would prefer pure bash/sh, but compact python / perl / ruby / etc one-liners would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using jq 1.5 (e.g. jq 1.5rc2 -- see http://stedolan.github.io/jq):

```
$ jq -n env
```

Comment: Wondering if anyone knows how to do this, but only passing a subset of the current environment's variables?

Comment: If you can specify the subset deterministically, it will be easy to implement in jq.  The jq manual is at https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

Comment: what's the rhyme/reason for this to work with `jq`? I tried using `jq -n echo "foo"` and that didn't work...so how does it recognize the `env` command?

Comment: `env` is a jq function.  Compare: `s=abc jq -n 'env.s'`; and: `s=abc jq -n '$ENV.s'`

Answer (score 16):

This works for me:

```
python -c 'import json, os;print(json.dumps(dict(os.environ)))'
```

It's pretty simple; the main complication is that `os.environ` is a dict-like object, but it is not actually a dict, so you have to convert it to a dict before you feed it to the json serializer.

Adding parentheses around the print statement lets it work in both Python 2 and 3, so it should work for the forseeable future on most *nix systems (especially since Python comes by default on any major distro).

Comment: That worked too. I'm going to go with the jq answer because of the ludicrous terseness, but this is good for more common UNIX dependency environments

Comment: Thanks for this. Based on your answer, I wrote a [small python snippet](https://gist.github.com/gableroux/d6b2c2f7a69ebcd8430ea59c9bcc62c0/#file-env-to-json-py) to read a `.env` file and output its values in json. There are probably better ways, but I needed this quickly :)

Answer (score 0):

@Alexander Trauzzi asked: "Wondering if anyone knows how to do this, but only passing a subset of the current environment's variables?"

I just found the way to do this:

```bash
jq -n 'env | {USER, HOME, PS1}'
```